# Synchronize subplot size

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

I can make figures the same size by setting `figsize` when calling `subplots`, but how would I make subplots the same size and letting figure size change to make room?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Some example data to display
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)
axs[0].plot(x, y)
axs[1].plot(x, y)

plt.show()

fig, axs = plt.subplots(3)
axs[0].plot(x, y)
axs[1].plot(x, y)
axs[2].plot(x, y)

plt.show()
```

[image: Two subplots]

[image: Three subplots]

Comment: It is rather complicated, due to varying size needed for axes labels, ticks with/without exponents, subtitles, overall title,  padding etc.. You can get a rude approximation can by setting a figsize.  E.g. `fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(8,6))` and `fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, figsize=(8,9))`.